# C#/WPF: Can I Store more that 1 type in Clipboard?

Tags: c#, wpf, clipboard

Can I Store more than 1 type in the Clipboard? Eg. like Text & Image. say the user pastes in a text editor, he gets the text and if he pastes in something like photoshop, he gets the image. I thought it was possible but I tried

```
Clipboard.Clear();
Clipboard.SetText(img.DirectLink);

BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(img.DirectLink);
bitmapImage.EndInit();

Clipboard.SetImage(bitmapImage);
```

and I always get the image

Comment: Well, AFAIK there's only one slot in the clipboard, since you put the image last, that would have to be expected...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The main problem is, methods you are using clear clipboard before putting data (that's why in particular they named "Set..." instead of "Add...").

[Clipboard.SetText (WinForms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydby206k.aspx) / [Clipboard.SetText (WPF)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597043.aspx) description from MSDN:

> (WinForms): Clears the Clipboard and then adds text data in the Text or UnicodeText format, depending on the operating system.

But a solution is relatively easy:

> To place data on the Clipboard in multiple formats, use the DataObject class or an IDataObject implementation. Place data on the Clipboard in multiple formats to maximize the possibility that a target application, whose format requirements you might not know, can successfully retrieve the data.

Check MSDN for details:

- WinForms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25w5tzxb.aspx
- WPF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.clipboard.aspx

---

UPDATE:

Added links to WPF variants.

To clarify @Björn comment:

> The MSDN page for System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText() does not state that the clipboard is cleared, even though that seems to be the case

Both methods (WPF/WinForms) internally calls to [OleSetClipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686623.aspx) so behaviour is similar (you can check http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=Clipboard.SetText).

I also checked both variants (WinForms/WPF) in console app and found they do the same.

Comment: sorry I'm late to the party; I was recently trying to get a picture and some text on the clipboard at the same time and it wasn't working. My code looked like this:

`dataObject.SetText("leText");`
`dataObject.SetImage(myImage);`
`Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject);`

In order to make it work I added an extra boolean "true" to the SetDataObject method:

`Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObject, true);`

check out the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9032673/clipboard-copying-objects-to-and-from)

Comment: The link to MSDN is actually for System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard, not System.Windows.Clipboard (which WPF should use). The MSDN page for System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText() does not state that the clipboard is cleared, even though that seems to be the case.

Answer (score 9):

As Nick says in the accepted answer: You have to use a DataObject (or IDataObject) to use multiple formats (otherwise each Set-call will clear the clipboard first).
Here is a code sample:

```
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.BeginInit();
bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri(img.DirectLink);
bitmapImage.EndInit();

DataObject d = new DataObject();
d.SetImage(bitmapImage);
d.SetText(img.DirectLink);
Clipboard.SetDataObject(d);
```