# can we copy clipboard text to a array

Tags: c#, clipboard

i tried to make a array list of 5 element in which recent 5 clipboard text is copied

but i am not able to do this every time clipboard text overwrites the previous one and in first array element

and prints only the last one i want to print all how can i do this.

if my case is possible thn please give me some solution

Comment: Can you show your code instead of problem description?

Comment: Have you tried using String.Join(', ', myArray)

Comment: -1, because nobdy can guess how your code works. Think about it before posting.

Answer (score 1):

How about: You manage a custom object while you read/write on [`Clipboard`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738.aspx). For instance, `MyCustomClipboardClass`.

Everytime you are about to move data on clipboard;

- Get your `MyCustomClipboardClass` object.
- Add  your text to it.
- Save that object onto clipboard.

See following:

```
[Serializable]
class MyCustomClipboardClass
{
    List<string> m_lstTexts = new List<string>();

    public void AddText(string str)
    {
        m_lstTexts.Add(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that, if I understand question correctly (if you want to keep last 5 clipboard items programatically):

```
    const int MaxItems = 5;
    static readonly List<string> ClipboardData = new List<string>();

    public static void SaveClipboard()
    {
        ClipboardData.Add(Clipboard.GetText());
        if (ClipboardData.Count > MaxItems) ClipboardData.RemoveAt(0);
    }

    // You don't need lines later, I show them just as example
    [STAThreadAttribute]
    static void Main()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Clipboard.SetText(i.ToString());
            SaveClipboard();
        }

        foreach (var s in ClipboardData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

If you need @KMan way check this question also: [C#/WPF Can I Store more that 1 type in Clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941472/c-wpf-can-i-store-more-that-1-type-in-clipboard)

---

So you have to call SaveClipboard() after each clipboard modification. All data will be gathered in ClipboardData

Comment: console app. shows error that clipboard doesnt found. for that  i have to include using System.Windows.Forms; in console app. program

Comment: Reference manually (via Right click on References -> AddReference) System.Windows.Forms, it will helps.

Comment: In WinForms you don't need my Main method it just demostrates how you can try to use SaveClipboard() and list contents..

Comment: hii... i add references the program is run successfully but it shows output 56789 all in new line but i expect it will show any copied data which is in clipboard :( :( :(

Comment: So, what *exactly* you want? Do you need to monitor clipboard data and gather data from any (including external) clipboard modification? Or do you need to programmatically gather data which *your own* program will add? You get 5..6..7..8.. thru I called `Clipboard.SetText()` as example and modify clipboard. Be sure to read `Clipboard` class details.